# How to update data in a table in an array form in Vue.js

Tags: php, mysqli, vue.js

So I have a query below that only works if I only have one data passed or to update, but when there's 2 or more, it's not working anymore:

```
public function update($id){
    $data = $this->request->all();
    $result = array($data);
    foreach($result as $x => $x_value) {
        $emp_key = $x_value['data'];
    }

    DB::table('employee')->where('emp_key',  $emp_key)->update([
        'group_code' => $id,
    ]);
}
```

I want to update the `group_code` of each `emp_key` to `0`.
Sample result when I `var_dump($result)`, following is the result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
 array(1) {
["data"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "123bcd"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "635bdd"
}
}
}
```

**print_r OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123bcd
        [1] => 635bdd
    )

)
```

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Is there anything about vue?

Comment: Can someone have any input on this please? I'm really stuck on this right now. Thanks.

Comment: your foreach loop just runs over all the available items in your dataset, untill it's done and then you only use the last resulting $emp_key to update the $id... Put your update (DB::table....=>$id) in the loop so it updates all the items.

Comment: @lovelace This doesn't do the trick :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your update query inside the foreach loop:

```
foreach($data['data'] as $x => $emp_key) {

     DB::table('employee')->where('emp_key',  $emp_key)->update([
        'group_code' => $id,
    ]);
 }
```

What your previous code was doing was that the `$emp_key` variable was only storing the last value in your loop thus it was the only one being updated by your query

Comment: Weew, already tried this one, but still doesn't work. It only updates the first Id.

Comment: your foreach is wrong since you have a multidimensional array. Let me update my answer

Comment: @ramedju do a `print_r($data);` and post the output

Comment: Updated the answer I used the `$data` variable instead since there's no need to do this `$result = array($data);` as `$data` is already an array.